# Get the local group a user is a member of

Tags: powershell

I'd like to only get the LOCAL group a user belongs to using powershell. So something like Get-membergroup Jake, and have it list the local groups Jake is a member of.

Comment: Local groups for a roaming active directory profile?

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried (show your code) and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: Usually I would post my code, but I don't know where to start. I'm not expecting a whole script, just someone that knows of a cmdlet or a series of that can point me in the correct direction. Since we're not querying anything AD related, Get-qaduser does not work, and get-localgroupmember requires you to know the group.

Comment: If you are using Win10 1607 and can use `Get-LocalGroupMember` then you can also use `Get-LocalGroup`. Thus you can do a ForEach loop and get the members of each group and check if the user is a member of it.

Comment: If you aren't using Win10 1607, then [this blog post by Boe Prox](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/11/get-all-members-of-a-local-group-using-powershell/) highlights how to get the relevant information without the new cmdlets.